# Charting Components

Tags: c#, charts

im looking for a charting class library like [Nevron](http://www.nevron.com/) or [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Charting/) that can handle with very big datasets (2 Millions points per second for example) are there better or more powerful Components? I need a few components to compare it among each other.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked the MS build in Charting Solution?
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx

It is for Winforms and ASP.net and as far as I remember there are plans to implement WPF support (<- but not sure)...

Download here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en

Documentation here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=EE8F6F35-B087-4324-9DBA-6DD5E844FD9F

Answer (score 1):

You cannot physically show more than 300-1200 pixels/inch on a printer and a lot less on a display.

Take those 2 million points and **summarise** every group of 1000-odd points (via mean, median, mode, maximum or minimum...), so that you end up with 2000 'summarised' points (this would be quick and easy to code). Charting 2000 summarised points makes much more sense for on-screen charting. Use a summary range of 100-500 points, if it will be printed (depending on printer DPI capability and chart size).

Internally, this is what most charting components will have to do, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not that simple - when you "summarize" the points using average for example you'll loose spikes in the data. It also depends on the series being plotted - it is one thing to summarize in a line chart with ascending x values and completely different thing when you summarize a xy scatter point chart. It also depends whether the user has zoomed the chart etc. so a professional charting library will have to take the level of detail (zoom factor), data spikes and series type into account.

In addition some charting libraries will use a direct interface to the video board (like OpenGL or DirectX) which is must faster than when you draw using GDI+ for example. I think you 're going in the right direction as the above two libraries are some of the best out there.